# Github Action exists with vode 141

Tags: docker, github, github-actions, action

I am the using reviewdog/languagetool action and get a very weird exit code with no further information.

```
Checking .wordlist-cleaned.txt...
reviewdog: this is not PullRequest build.
2023-11-24 10:19:27.262 GMT INFO  org.languagetool.server.LanguageToolHttpHandler Handling POST /v2/check
2023-11-24 10:19:33.846 GMT INFO  org.languagetool.server.TextChecker Check done: 19505 chars, en-US, requestId: null, #1, null, 0/9 matches, 6548ms, agent:-, sent, q:0, h:1, dH:1, r:1, m:all, premium: false
2023-11-24 10:19:33.850 GMT INFO  org.languagetool.server.LanguageToolHttpHandler Handled request in 6599ms; sending code 200
##[debug]Docker Action run completed with exit code 141
##[debug]Finishing: Run reviewdog/action-languagetool@v1
```

Anyone an idea?

Comment: Is this fixed? From "**reviewdog: this is not PullRequest build**" in above logs shows that your workflow isn't triggered with `pull_request` event.